# I get ThrottlingException while using AWS translate api

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, boto

I am running  this code to translate

```
translate = boto3.client(service_name='translate',
    aws_access_key_id="secret",
    aws_secret_access_key="secret",
    region_name='eu-central-1',
    use_ssl=True)

translate.translate_text(Text=data,SourceLanguageCode="de",TargetLanguageCode="en").get("TranslatedText")
```

Code runs properly for most of the test  but suddenly throws the following error:

```
An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the TranslateText operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded
```

How to handle this exception?

Comment: [exponential backoff](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) is usually used to deal with such errors. Maybe worth considering this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link has answers to throttling exceptions
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/what-is-limits.html#limits-throttling
The service scales up the fleet based on the traffic pattern. I wonder at what TPS you hit the throttling limits.

&

Have you also tried a different region like eu-west-1?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into a similar issue and did not want to use [asynchronous batch requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/async.html), because I'm using multiple translation APIs and would rather keep the code the same for all.

Here are payload limits for different translation APIs. This may impact throttling (e.g. calling the Amazon Translate API multiple times per second with a small payload worked just fine):

- Amazon: [5,000 bytes (for synchronous real-time translations.)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/what-is-limits.html)
- DeepL: [The request size should not exceed 30kbytes.](https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/accessing-the-api/limits/)
- Google Cloud: ["We recommend the total content be less than 30k codepoints"](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects/translateText).
- Yandex Cloud: [The maximum total length of all strings is 10000 characters.](https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/translate/api-ref/Translation/translate)

Amazon's limit is clearly the lowest.

Now for the **throttling limits on Amazon Translate**:

- Amazon does not indicate what the throttling limit is for the normal API, the docs merely state:

  > Amazon Translate scales to serve customer operational traffic. If you encounter sustained throttling, contact AWS Support.
- But [docs for AWS GovCloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/govcloud-translate.html) do mention:

  > The default throttling limits for AWS GovCloud (US) are set to 5000 Bytes per 10 seconds per language pair and 10 transactions per second per language pair. You can request an increase for any of the limits using the [Amazon Translate service limits increase form](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-translate).

For my use case (translating HTML larger than 5,000 bytes after splitting it into chunks), ended up implementing a simple wait of **15 seconds between API calls** to avoid hitting the throttling limits. In my tests, translating a payload of 2K to 5K bytes 200 times, with a sleep time of 15 seconds between calls, all ran successfully (whereas with a wait time of just 11 seconds I'd still get some `ThrottlingException`.)

If I were to code it better, I'd probably implement **retries with exponential backoff** like Marcin suggested. Or would **request a limit increase** to make my life easier and my experience more consistent across APIs.

Comment: I contacted AWS support to ask them if the rate-limit could be altered, but was told it wasn't an option. They stated, as you mentions too, that the service will scale to meet the demand. In my usecase that just doesn't work as the translations comes in burst of 3-6 translations at a time

Comment: @JensVæverHartfelt I'd just implement exponential backoff if I were you. I did for another project that uses the ChatGPT API and it's fairly easy to implement (with Tenacity if you're using Python), while it'll make your service much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the **asynchronous** call `start_text_translation_job()` instead of the **synchronous** call `translate_text()`? Then you would have a much higher limit, instead of 5000 bytes, you would have 1,000,000 characters * 1,000,000 documents * 10 batches: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/what-is-limits.html#limits-throttling

**Synchronous Real-Time Translation Limits:**

```
Description Limit
Character encoding  UTF-8
Maximum document size (UTF-8 characters)    5,000 bytes
```

**Asynchronous Batch Translation Limits:**

```
Description Limit
Character encoding  UTF-8
Maximum number of characters per document   1,000,000
Maximum size per document   20 MB
Maximum number of documents in batch    1,000,000
Maximum size of total documents in batch    5 GB
Maximum number of parallel batch translation jobs   10
```

The code for the **asynchronous** `start_text_translation_job()` call can be find here:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/translate.html

```
response = client.start_text_translation_job(
    JobName='string',
    InputDataConfig={
        'S3Uri': 'string',
        'ContentType': 'string'
    },
    OutputDataConfig={
        'S3Uri': 'string'
    },
    DataAccessRoleArn='string',
    SourceLanguageCode='string',
    TargetLanguageCodes=[
        'string',
    ],
    TerminologyNames=[
        'string',
    ],
    ClientToken='string'
)
```

Comment: this doesn't fit in my use case, since it's required to create objects s3

anyway, retrying with exponential backoff solved the problem.

Comment: yes, the text which have to be translated needs to be transfered first to S3 and the results are stored to S3 again. But depending of use case this can be automated and increase extremely the limitations.

Comment: Just a note for anyone stumbling upon this solution. Using the task-approach is very slow. I tried this approach and tasks were at least 10 minutes to finish, sometimes up to 20 minutes. Just a heads up in case this is a dealbreaker to anyone else (as it was in my usecase)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a few months old now but the solution [here](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/882#issuecomment-338846339) worked well for me and let me avoid needing to write my own backoff code:

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

config = Config(retries=dict(max_attempts=10))
region = "us-east-1"

translate = boto3.client(
    service_name="translate",
    region_name=region,
    use_ssl=True,
    config=config,
)
```

Even in us-east-1 I seem to hit a few retries, and it's much slower than Google Cloud Translate (which I also hit from Python in the same script), but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a python question, but it seems this solution is universal to almost all AWS SDK's (including boto - here is a list of compatible SDK's with this solution: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-retry-behavior.html#feature-retry-behavior-sdk-compat)

If you specify `retryMode` and `maxAttempts` then it seems that the SDK handles timeouts and retries automatically.

This is from the javascript SDK, but should work the same with python according to the list above, though the configuration-keys could be named differently:

#### ❌ This doesn't work and will cause rate-limits for multiple requests at once

```js
const { TranslateClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-translate");

const translateClient = new TranslateClient({
  region: "eu-central-1",
});
```

#### ✅ This works and will not cause rate-limits

```js
const { TranslateClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-translate");

const translateClient = new TranslateClient({
  region: "eu-central-1",
  maxAttempts: 20, // How many attempts to make (default is 3)
  retryMode: "ExponentialBackoff", // Couldn't find any explanations for which retryModes is available through the docs but "ExponentialBackoff" is mentioned in the link above and seems to work ‍♂️
});
```