# AWS Translate large HTML with Python

Tags: python, html, amazon-web-services, translation

I have a large text in HTML format that needs to be translated in different languages using Amazon Translate API (It needs to be AWS, no option of using other service).

Amazon has a limit of ~5000 chars to be translated per call so I need to "split" in sentences the large texts.

In the HTML I have many tags like DIVs, IMG, links, bold and italic tags, etc.

Here is my actual approach:

1. Take the HTML text and pass it through Python HTMLParser
2. If the open tag is a `<p>` get the Data (using `handle_data` function)
3. "Split" the data in sentences that are less than 5000 chars altogether
4. Translate each block of "less than 5000 chars" sentences and join them in one big translated text
5. Reconstruct the HTML with the translated text

The problem here is that I have no idea how to reconstruct the HTML, and identify tags like `<a>, <b>, <i>, <img>`, etc. that are inside the `<p>`.

Any other approach or solution?

If you have example code, it would be nice because I have no idea how to override the `handle` functions of the parser

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ran into a similar challenge: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66075042/1717535

Answer (score 0):

For the specified use case, when it's a single, not very large file, and you need the response instantly, `translate_text` method should be fine.

In case you have many HTML files, you could use the batch translation job with `StartTextTranslationJob`

1. Store a set of documents in an input folder inside of an Amazon S3
   bucket.
2. Start a batch translation job.
3. As part of your request, provide Amazon Translate with an IAM role
   that has read access to the input Amazon S3 folder. The role must
   also have read and write access to an output Amazon S3 bucket.
4. Monitor the progress of the batch translation job.
5. Retrieve the results of the batch translation job from the specified
   output bucket.

See more here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/async.html